# my sticky scrolling navigation not working in the js file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-chrome

All the code here works expect the if else statement in the scrolling function. I'm using chrome and loading jQuery from cdn and its comes before any js file . everything would load perfectly fine but the scrolling navigation part doesn't work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict"
    $('.slider').ripples({
        dropRadius: 14,
        perturbance: 0.01,

    });

    $(".text").typed({
        strings: ["<strong>leveraging </strong><strong class='primary'>Digital Technologies</strong>", "<strong>To Transform </strong><strong class='primary'>Your Business</strong>"],
        typespeed: 0,
        loop: true
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (top >= 60) {
            $("nav").addClass('secondary');
        } else
        if ($("nav").hasClass('secondary')) {
            $("nav").removeClass('secondary');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works. First check if there are no console errors caused by other libraries. Then check if there is enough space to scroll "60px" by adding css to the body "min-height: 500vh;" or changing 60px to 1px.